# MySQL GROUP BY if Multiple Numbered Columns are Close to Each Other (+/- 1)

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with a large list of coordinates (x, y, z). I want to find the most common spots, but when the same place is logged, it isn't identical. For example, x could be 496.0481 or 496.3904, but that is actually the same place.

When I do the following query I get a list of the absolute exact matches, but those are very few and far between:

```
SELECT x, y, z, COUNT(*) AS coords
FROM coordinates 
GROUP BY x, y, z
ORDER BY coords DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

How can I adjust this to be grouped by each of x, y, and z to be +/- 1 to catch a larger area? I've tried a mix of IF and BETWEEN statements but can't seem to get anything to work.

If I do `GROUP BY round(x), round(y), round(z)`, that gets a larger range but doesn't capture if the number goes from 496 to 497 even if they are just slightly different.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You need to clean your data first before you start doing SQL. One way is to add the coordinates into some ANN structure (Annoy or FAISS) and for each point to a KNN search. Better way is to do a clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Very naive way:

```
select t1.x as x1, t1.y as y1, t1.z as z1, t2.x as x2, t2.y as y2, t2.z as z2 
from coordinates t1
join coordinates t2 on sqrt(power(t2.x-t1.x, 2) + power(t2.y-t1.y, 2) + power(t2.z-t1.z, 2)) <= 1
```

For each coordinates (`t1`) query finds all other coordinates (`t2`) that dinstanced less or equal than 1 from each other.

But this query has very bad performance: O(n^2)

Comment: Thank you for this. It looks like it works, but ya it does take a while and I'm looking to 100x the data. Also, all the top results are a single location along with every result around it as they are all populating as near each other which, I guess is correct, but I want other locations. Hmm. Thanks Leemellaret